# xUnit Unit Test project not reading App.config

Tags: .net, unit-testing, xunit

I have a .NET Framework 4.5.2 unit test project with xUnit.  Inside my unit test project I have an `App.config` file with the same `appSettings` as my `Web.config`.

When I run my test, `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[<keyname>]` always returns null - indicating that it's not reading the `App.config` file.

Looking in the `bin` directory I can see that I have a `MyProject.Tests.UnitTests.dll.config` file that appears to have the same contents as my `App.config`.

Is this a bug with xUnit? Do I have to do any xUnit configuration to get `ConfigurationManager` to work?

Answer (score 3):

If you've stumbled upon this then the answer unfortunately this may not be the answer you're looking for, however I resolved it by just using NUnit rather than XUnit.

In my attempt to work around the issue, I'd decided to create a `Configuration` class that implements an `IConfiguration` interface and inject that wherever I wanted to get AppSettings.  I then faced another problem where my mock wouldn't set up, giving me this [issue](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/issues/308).  At that point I just gave up and switched, where my test worked straight away.

Ultimately the problem seems to be a combination of using Resharper, XUnit, and .NET Framework.

Comment: Disappointing.  xUNit has its own properties mechanism that can be used but I too want to use App.Config because that it how applications that use my library will have to work and I want to simulate that during testing.

Answer (score 0):

After a little research & experimentation, I found a way to get this working with xUnit *for my needs*.  Instead of creating a new app.config, I simply put my settings in **the .config file  that the VS build automagically created in my bin\debug folder**, for me it was called **MyDLL.Tests\bin\Debug\net472\MyDLL.Tests.dll.config**.  Simple and it starting working immediately.

**Details:**
I added this section for my setting, immediately before the final  tag.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ExpireMins" value="5" />
</appSettings>
```

**UPDATE:**
**Better yet**, I found a way to do the above in VS2017:

1. Select Test Project in Solution Explorer

   2. Add > New Item... > Application Configuration File & name it "App.config".
   3. Add your settings (e.g. see XML above) to the App.config.
   4. Clean and rebuild solution.  Your new settings should now appear in the DLL.configs! :)

Note: For some reason the above did not work for me first time.  The name "App.config" & project (Test) used may both be critical(?).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem seems to be fixed by upgrading my test project from targeting .NET Framework 4.5 to 4.5.2.

The problem seems to be related to this:
[Running xunit.net tests in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927263/running-xunit-net-tests-in-vsts)

If you do follow this approach, take note of other caveats, like `Console.WriteLine()` not working in xUnit 2.x:
[Using ReSharper, how to show debug output during a long-running unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092438/using-resharper-how-to-show-debug-output-during-a-long-running-unit-test)